# Time Stamp Response verification using openssl

Tags: openssl, timestamp, certificate, verification, ca

I have problems verifying a time stamp response using openssl:

When I use

```
openssl ts -verify -digest 'c9369ce7fe345436e4a14e63708f166adcdccf9d' -in '/tmp/1806078973W4qE6s' -CAfile 'certs.pem'
```

I get the error message

> error:2107C080:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_get0_signers:signer certificate
>   not found:pk7_smime.c:466:

The CAfile is in the format

> subject=/C=DE/ST=Berlin/L=Berlin/O=D-Trust GmbH/CN=*.d-trust.net
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFgDCCBGigAwIBAgIDFx7uMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRF
>   MRUwEwYDVQQKDAxELVRydXN0IEdtYkgxJjAkBgNVBAMMHUQtVFJVU1QgU1NMIENs
>   ....Blablabla......
>   neRy7dzB6nTUBxoYcom/BHoveYcbO1fimPtNPNv4PWcvS4bCkeZQ62sbTu6NwO0i
>   z7D9bcd8/0DSVwoMDkLDn+WkEpk=
>   -----END CERTIFICATE----- subject= /C=DE/O=D-Trust GmbH/CN=D-TRUST SSL Class 3 CA 1 2009
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFMjCCBBqgAwIBAgIDCZBjMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAME0xCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRF
>   MRUwEwYDVQQKDAxELVRydXN0IEdtYkgxJzAlBgNVBAMMHkQtVFJVU1QgUm9vdCBD
>   ....Blablabla......
>   Wz2KhjFDmAeFg2J89YcpeJJEEJXoweAkgJEEwwEIfJ2yLjYo78RD0Rvij/+zkfj9
>   +dSvTiZTuqicyo37qNoYHgchuqXnKodhWkW89oo2NKhfeNHHbqvXEJmx0PbI6YyQ 50GnYECZRHNKhgbPEtNy/QetU53aWlTlvu4NIwLW5XVsrxlQ2Zw=
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

I go the certificate using

```
openssl s_client -connect tsp.d-trust.net:443 -showcerts
```

My questions are:
Is the CAfile inocorrect or do I have to configure something on openssl?

Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to store the certificate separately and add it to the command line This works for me using OpenSSL 1.1.0

```
$ openssl ts -verify -CAfile certs/ca-chain.pem -untrusted certs/tsa.pem \
    -digest 9c04cd6372077e9b11f70ca111c9807dc7137e4b -in timestamp.tsr
Using configuration from /opt/openssl/ssl/openssl.cnf
Verification: OK
```